# Not able to upload image in created album: Imgur python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-uploading, python-3.5, imgur

I am trying to create an album and upload images into it using [imgurpython](https://github.com/Imgur/imgurpython). However, I am not able to attach images to the album. It is giving me following error: `(403) The album you're requesting does not belong to your account`. Following is my code:

```
client = ImgurClient(client_id, client_secret)
def CreateAlbumAndUploadImages(albumName,albumDescription,images):
    fields = {}
    fields['title'] = albumName
    fields['description'] = albumDescription
    fields['privacy'] = 'public'
    x = client.create_album(fields)
    print(x)
    y = client.album_add_images(x['id'],images)  #error here
    print(y)
    return x
def UploadPhoto(images):
    config = {
        'name':  'some image name here',
        'title': 'some title here',
        'description': 'some description here'}    
    image = client.upload_from_path(image_path, config=config, anon=False)
    print("Done")
    print(image)
    return image

def main():
    #x = CreateAlbum('Album 101','Album 101 desciption')
    id = []
    id.append( UploadPhoto(['image1.jpg'])['id'])
    id.append( UploadPhoto(['image2.jpg'])['id'])
    x = CreateAlbumAndUploadImages('albumNameHere','some description here',id)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**NOTE:** I am trying to build a bot, hence calling authorize on web is not an option

Comment: Were you able to get this working after adding `set_user_auth` mentioned in your accepted answer? What was missing, I am stuck in a similar situation and would like to know the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and figured it out by realizing that I hadn't fully  authenticated the client.  To do so you must do this:

```
client = ImgurClient(client_id,client_secret, refresh_token)
client.set_user_auth(access_token, refresh_token)
```

Then it should work.  If you need to get access and refresh token then do:

```
client = ImgurClient(client_id, client_secret)
print client.get_auth_url('pin') #go to page and copy down pin
creds = client.authorize(raw_input('Pin: '), 'pin')
client.set_user_auth(creds['access_token'], creds['refresh_token'])
#You will only need to do this once per user, store tokens
```

After that, just save your access token and refresh token and just include it in the first example.

Comment: I have tried this approach with the album id, it throwed an error  `imgurpython.helpers.error.ImgurClientError: (400) You are not the owner of album<ALBUM ID>`

Comment: @GovindKailas Did you solve it?